# Почему созданный Form2 открывается и моментально закрывается?

Tags: c#

Создал вторую форму Form2:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
Form2.Show();

this.Close();
```

Первый закрывается, а второй в долю секунды открывается и закрывается. В чем дело?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.mainform

Comment: нашел выход в this.Hide();

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, потому что приложение настроено так, что оно считается открытым, пока открыта первая форма. Именно такое поведение по-умолчанию в WinForms создается, насколько я помню.

Comment: что делать? Я новичок в си шарпе @dog_funtom

Comment: google ApplicationContext

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, вероятно, `Form1` является главным окном приложения. Закрытие главного окна приложения всегда закрывает это приложение.

Честно говоря, мне сложно понять, зачем может понадобиться такое поведение, когда вместо главного окна приложения появляется другое. Быть может, лучшим выходом из ситуации будет изменить логику интерфейса?

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
Form2.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

Comment: ну тогда он не закрывает форму1. Мне это ни к чему же @Мурад

Comment: Тогда надо создовать новое окно в отдельном потоке и там его показывать.

Comment: var thered = new Thread(ShowForm2);
            thered.Start();
            Close();

 private static void ShowForm2()
        {
            new Form2().ShowDialog();
        }

Comment: @Мурад Адовая жесть.

Comment: Ну да контекст лучше :)

Comment: я додумался до легкого метода: this.Hide(); ))

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `Form2` является полем формы `Form1`, при закрытии `Form1`, соответственно будет освобождаться память, занятая экземпляром `Form2`, то есть закрываться.

Comment: что делать? Я новичок в си шарпе @Flash

Comment: метод Hide

Answer (score 0):

1. Создай класс вроде:

`public class FormManager
    {
       public static Form Form1;
       public static Form Form2;
    }`

2. В program.cs вместо инициализации форм1 локально -- инициализируй ее в FormManager.Form1
3. в месте где ты запускаешь форму 2 вызови инициализацию формы2 в FormManager.Form2

должно быть то,что тебе нужно. Хотя может я что-то и упустил. Но подход именно такой. Хотя еще лучше будет, если переменные будут НЕ статичными. Но тогда кода больше и тебе прийдется с ним будет еще повозится.

---

Вариант 2 -- работать через .Hide() формы1. Но нужно не забывать что в таковом случае

1. она будет висеть в оперативке и занимать там место
2. Ты скорее всего завтычишь и оставишь апликуху висеть в оперативке даже после закрытия формы2.

**Так что с таким подходом нужно быть ооочень осторожным.** И я настоятельно рекомендую его не использовать с даной целью.

---

На вопрос "почему" ответили до меня Maxim Kamalov и eigenein

Answer (score -1):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

this.Visible = false;

Form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.